# Подключение CSS к HTML с Go linux

Tags: html, css, linux, golang

Проблемы с подключением css к проекту. В HTML у меня:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- Стили сайта -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <img class="imgstars" src="https://thumb.tildacdn.com/tild3531-3462-4931-b561-653663313033/-/format/webp/image.png">
    <h1 class="h1">Hello</h1>
    <h1 class="h1">Hi</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

А CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: blue;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
}

h1 {
    color: green;
}
```

Код на Go:

```
import (
"html/template"
"net/http"
)

var tpl *template.Template

func home_page(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
tpl.Execute(w, nil)
}

func handleRequest() {
http.HandleFunc("/", home_page)
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func main() {
tpl, _ = tpl.ParseFiles("index.html")
handleRequest()
}
```

У меня не меняется ни текст ни фон.

Comment: А при чём тут Go?

Comment: Покажите код сервера, как вы раздаёте файлы

Comment: @Pak Uula добавил код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы обрабатываете только запросы `GET /`, запросы `GET /style.css` ваш сервер отвергает (вероятнее всего, возвращает 404). Поэтому браузер не отрисовывает стили, он о них просто не знает.

Варианты решения:

1. Статический сервер, отдаёт файлы из определённой папки, включая `index.html` и `style.css`: [`http.FileServer`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#FileServer)
2. Добавьте обработчик для `style.css`. Для этого можно использовать [`ServeMux`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ServeMux), чтобы обслуживать несколько   эндпоинтов.

Например, можно сделать вот так:

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    runServer()
}

func runServer() {
    indexHtml := NewServeFile("text/html", "site/index.html")
    stylesCss := NewServeFile("text/css", "site/styles.css")

    mux := http.NewServeMux()
    mux.Handle("/", indexHtml)
    mux.Handle("/index.html", indexHtml)
    mux.Handle("/styles.css", stylesCss)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", mux)
}

// Передаёт один статический файл
type ServeFile struct {
    contentType string
    fileName    string
}

func NewServeFile(contentType, fileName string) *ServeFile {
    return &ServeFile{
        contentType: contentType,
        fileName:    fileName,
    }
}

func (sf *ServeFile) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    file, err := os.Open(sf.fileName)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "No such file", http.StatusNotFound)
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()

    w.Header().Add("Content-Type", sf.contentType)
    io.Copy(w, file)
}
```